# How to prevent excel frommaking any changes in a CSV file when opening it

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have multiple .csv files with data I generated on another program. I want to open each of these files, copy all data from it and paste it all on an existing workbook on excel. My problem is that when I open the csv file with excel it automatically divides the csv text in three or more columns so that, later, I can't convert the data using the Text to Columns data tool (or any other tool, as this auto-conversion from excel breaks some single values in two different numbers). Is there any way I can prevent excel from making ANY changes at all when I open a csv file?

Comment: Do you know why exactly Excel is breaking your data? Are there instances of the delimiter (e.g. comma) within the values themselves which should not be treated as delimiters? Or is Excel splitting the data by a fixed width? CSV is a plain text file, so in theory the task can be handled with custom VBA code if need be.

Comment: Upload a sample test file that demonstrates the problem to some public file sharing site.  Most likely you can `IMPORT` rather than `OPEN` the file to do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify in the csv file that it is text. You do this by putting your number in quotes and preceeding with and equal sign, eg:

```
="001145",="55666",="02133"
```

The easiest way to do this would be to do a find-replace on , with ",=", replacing end of lines (you might need to use an advanced editor like Notepad++ for this) with "\r\n=" and doing the start and end of the file manually.

Comment: I don't know why this is downvoted, but I upvoted it.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid opening CSV directly into Excel by the double click from Windows Explorer and consider either of the two options:

**Manual User Interface**

Open Excel program by itself without any file. Under *Open*, browse and select the csv file. You will then walk through the import process wizard. Be sure to select 1) delimited (not fixed) - comma type; 2) headers are on first row; 3) IMPORTANTLY: defined each column as *Text* type.

You may want to check off the quoting option to enclose values since commas may be placed within text strings and may be confused with the delimited comma separator. Hence, on automated double click, Excel returned multiple columns for each comma separation. Even more, have the software producing csv files to quote enclose values with potential commas within it.

**Automated VBA Code**

Import the csv into Excel with [QueryTables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/querytable-object-excel) but after formatting all cells to *Text* which preserves all data types, specifically by setting [.NumberFormat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-numberformat-property-excel) to `@`:

```
Function ImportCSV()
    Dim qt As QueryTable

    csvfile = "C:\Path\To\CSV\File.csv"

    ' FORMAT ALL CELLS AS TEXT
    ActiveSheet.Cells.NumberFormat = "@"

    ' ADD QUERYTABLE
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & csvfile, _
        Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote 
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False

            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    ' REMOVE QUERYTABLE
    For Each qt In currwb.Sheets(2).QueryTables
        qt.Delete
    Next qt

    Set qt = Nothing
End Function
```